# how to get data of list inside list using thymeleaf ?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i have two entities particiapants and XrayFieldRadiology. they have onetoone relationship. so whenever i select participants the related XrayFieldRadiology is also selected. now i need to show all those database on my table and form.

my html file looks like this.

**Xraystatusform.html**

```
    <div class="box-body" >
                        <span class="successMessage" th:text="${dataSuccess}" style="color: green; align-self:flex-end"></span>
                        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Person Id</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                                <th>Sex</th>
                                <th>District</th>
                                <th>VDC/MUNICIPAL</th>
                                <th>Ward No.</th>
                                <th>Xray Status</th>
                                <th>Remarks</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody  th:each="persons : ${part}">
                                <form  method="post" th:action="@{/xraystatus(id=${persons.id})}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
                                    <td th:text="${persons.id}" id="xrayid"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${persons.name}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${persons.lastName}"></td >
                                    <td th:text="${persons.age}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${persons.sex}"> </td>
                                    <td th:text="${persons.district}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${persons.district}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${persons.wardNo}"></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox"  >
                                            <select name="xraystatus" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);" style="width:61px"  >
                                                <!--<option th:each="xraydata:${xraydata}" th:text="${xraydata.xrayStatus}"></option>-->
                                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                                <option value="0">No</option>
                                                <option value="2">Possible</option>
                                                <option value="3">Exempted</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>


                                    <td >
                                        <!--<div id="ifYes6" style="display:none; height:30px" >-->
                                            <input type="text" name="remarks"  >
                                        <!--</div>-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button> </td>
                                </form>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

my controller returns data like this.

[data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXhTQ.png)

on my input field remarks i need to load data of remarks e.g here blindman. and on xraystatus e.g 0,1(according to database).

my table so far looks like this.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz1pK.png)

so by using thymeleaf how can i access the list inside the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your data right, it should be as simple as:

```
<input type="text" name="remarks" th:value="${persons.xrayFieldRadiology != null ? persons.xrayFieldRadiology.remarks : ''}" />
```

Comment: well thanks a lot for this however i got an another problem. if all the rows are getting data then it works but if null is being returned it throws error. and in my case the field should be empty if no data is returned else it should be added with returned data.

Comment: great it works now. i was trying to use conditional expression like this 

${persons.xrayFieldRadiology.remarks } ?${persons.xrayFieldRadiology.remarks} : 'none'

but what you edited there works perfectly. much appreciate your time and effort to help me. i will mark your answer as useful.